# .htaccess - Can I redirect everything except one pdf file, with all redirects going to the same PDF

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have vhosts set up for different brands, the only thing on these is a single PDF Voucher. Is there a way I can redirect everything excluding the pdf file to this pdf file using .htaccess

eg. *example.com/voucher.pdf*

so if anyone goes to anywhere else

eg *example.com/index.html* or *example.com/random/dir/voucher.pdf*

It all gets redirect here :

*example.com/voucher.pdf*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it - Here is my solution for anyone that needs something similar

`RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule ^$ /file.pdf [R=301] 

RewriteRule ^((?!file.pdf).+)$ /file.pdf [R=301,L]`

This redirects from the root to the pdf file, and then it redirects everything except file.pdf to file.pdf